# Estimating plex tubing purchase

Tags: plumbing, pex

I am in the planning stages of building a new 4300 sqft home for my family. I am working to build out how much it will cost to run all the supply lines for my plumbing (contracting out the drains). The one thing I am not certain is how to estimate the length of 1/2" plex I will be needing. I am planning on using a Manabloc manifold for distribution and have the following plumbing connections

- 5 Lavatory Sinks
- 1 Kitchen Sink
- 1 Washing Machine
- 1 Laundry Sink
- 4 Baths (shower or tub)
- 1 Garage sink

(Cold Only)

- 3 Toilets
- 2 Hose Bibs
- 1 Ice maker

For a grand total of 13 hot connections and 19 cold connections. Mechanics closet is centrally located in the basement so no super long runs from one end of the house to the other.

Any advice on how to estimate my total length needed?

Comment: It's easier to work with multiple shorter rolls, and better to keep them independently boxed up until you need to use them. Is something wrong with just actually measuring and then rounding up to the next level?

Comment: That seems super dependent on the geometry of your house.